# Mesurability of Wiener Process

Tags: measure-theory, brownian-motion, filtrations

Let $(W_u)_{u\geq0}$ be a Wiener process defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb P, \mathscr{F}, \sigma(W_u)_{u\geq0})$ where $\sigma(W_t)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $W_t$. Let $s>t$.

**Is $W_t$ mesurable with respect to $\sigma(W_s)$?** My understanding is that it is not the case, but I am unsure on how to prove it.

**Background**: I have read that for a Brownian Motion $(W_u)_u$, if $0<t<s$ then:
$$E\left(W_tW_s|W_s\right)=\frac{t}{s} W_s^2$$
whereas I would have expected it to be equal to $W_tW_s$. The reason given for the result is that $W_t$ is not $\sigma(W_s)$-measurable, i.e. $E(W_t|W_s)\not= W_t$. I am trying to understand this.

Comment: Yes, of course it is, becuase $\sigma(W_s)\supset\sigma(W_t)$.

Comment: The appropriate $\sigma$-fields here are $\sigma(W_s: 0\le s\le t)$ for $t\ge 0$.

Comment: @Math1000 I updated my question with more background.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I updated my question with some additional background.